# Can not add validation component to form component. Showing error Can't bind to 'control' since it isn't a known property of 'app-errorMessages'

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular8, angular-validation

I am building an angular app with the below structure.

```
--app
    --shared(module)
        --validation-message(component)
    --core(module)
        --user
            --create(component)
    --security(module)
        --login(component)
```

In the `validation-message` component, I have the template to show the form validation message. I added the form validation successfully in `create` component in `core` module. But I had to add the below line in `core.module.ts` file

```
import { ValidationMessagesComponent } from '<path>';
```

**and added the component in `declarations` and `exports`**.

Then I import `CoreModule` to `app.module.ts` file. I added like this because adding `ValidationMessagesComponent` to `AppModule` was not working.

Now I need to add the validation to `LoginComponent`. But I am unable to add the `ValidationMessagesComponent` to the `SecurityModule`. It is showing error the `ValidationMessagesComponent` is already in two modules `CoreModule` and `SecurityModule`.

How can I make the `ValidationMessageComponent` work with the `LoginComponent`?

The validation component is like below

**validation-message.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from '../../core/services/validation/validation.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-errorMessages',
  template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage | translate}}</div>`
})
export class ValidationMessagesComponent {

  @Input() control: FormControl;

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Function to get the form validation error message
   *
   * @readonly
   * @memberof ValidationMessagesComponent
   */
  get errorMessage() {
    for (const propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'src/app/core/services/storage/local-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})

@Input() control: FormControl;

export class LoginComponent {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  title = 'Login';
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  login = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  };
  submitted = false;
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private localStorage: LocalStorageService
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(): void {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl(this.login.username, [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      password: new FormControl(this.login.password, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): any {
  }
}
```

**in "login.component.html" I added the line below the username filed**

```
<app-errorMessages [control]="loginForm.controls.userName" class="error-msg messages text-left text-danger"></app-errorMessages>
```

Here I am getting the error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'control' since it isn't a known property of 'app-errorMessages'.
>   1. If 'app-errorMessages' is an Angular component and it has 'control' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-errorMessages' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component

**What am I doing wrong? Please help. I am not getting any clue and stuck up here.**

Comment: Are you exporting `ValidationMessagesComponent` from your shared module?

Comment: @FredrikLundin, I tried that way. But I am having angular translation imports in app module. After use of shared module with `ValidationMessagesComponent`, the translation is not working but no errors